# JAX-RS webservice serving excel files from ajax call, how to show save dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS webservice that creates an excel file as a byte array and returns it to my javascript application,
the service works as I can inspect the response with firebug and it contains the headers I set and the bytes containing the excel file.

However I thought by setting the content-disposition header there would be a save dialog, seems not. 
Below I've pasted the headers I'm getting in my response, is there anything I forgot?

```
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=file.xls
Content-Length  17920
Content-Type    application/vnd.ms-excel
Date    Thu, 10 Jan 2013 07:07:49 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By    Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
```

The ajax call currently doesn't have a success function, do I need to write some kind of function to show the save dialog or is it sufficient that I set additional headers, if so which ones?

Thanks
J.

Comment: Instead of using ajax just do a `window.location.href = 'path/to/xlsfile/';`

Comment: there is no actual path to the excel it's never saved to disc, is there another way?

Comment: Its the same request url used in the ajax request, if the ajax request is a `post` request then use a form and post it to an invisible iframe.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Musa above, get rid of AJAX and just forward your user to the URL which returns Excel data with exactly the headers you use now (they are correct).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

I kept the ajax call because I'm sending a lot of parameters and arrays of data in a specified json format to the server side, however I returned a base64encoded string which I added to a hidden form which pointed to a link on the server side which sets the headers in a response with the decoded string, not the most elegant solution but it does the trick